# Merging large dataframe with smaller one (the large one is provided as buffer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask

I'm new to pandas and I would like to use your help.

I have two files, one of them is really big (100G+), which I need to merge based on some columns. I skip some lines in the big file, thus I get the file as buffer to the read_csv method.

Firsy, I tried to use pandas. However, when I tried to open the file using pandas, the process was killed by the OS.

```
with open(self.all_file, 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line.startswith('##'):
          pos = f.tell()
          line = f.readline()
    f.seek(pos)
    return pd.read_csv(f,sep='\t')
```

Afterwards, I tried to use dask instead of pandas, however dask can't get a buffer as input for read_csv method and it fails.

```
    return dd.read_csv(f,sep='\t')
```

How can I open large file as buffer and merge the two dataframes?

Thank you!

Comment: Performing a merge is straightforward with dask. For example, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467495/4057186) shows how to do this.

Comment: Why does the large `DataFrame` have to be provided as a buffer? Is this a requirement? Or, can you just read the file using dask `.read_csv` directly?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample (first 5 rows) of each file?

Comment: @edesz I provide it as a buffer because I am skipping couple of lines (vcf header lines)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

- you know the line numbers that you want to skip
- since these are VCF header lines, these lines occur only at the start of the file

So, you can still use `dd.read_csv` since [it accepts keywords](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv) from [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) such as `skiprows`

- see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20637559/4057186) for a `pandas` example with `skiprows`

  - if `skiprows` is an integer (eg. 2), then `.read_csv` will skip 2 rows
  - if `skiprows` is a list of integers (eg. [2,3]), then `.read_csv` will skip the line numbers (in the `.csv` file), starting at line number 0

So, you can read both files into `.csv` files with `dask`

```
df_1 = dd.read_csv('file_1.csv', skiprows=2, sep='\t') # skip line numbers 1, 2
df_2 = dd.read_csv('file_2.csv', skiprows=[10, 16]) # skip line numbers 11, 17
```

Then to merge the 2 `DataFrame`s with `dask` [`.merge`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.merge)

```
df_merged = dd.merge(df_1, df_2, left_on='abcd', right_on='abcde')
```

If this is what you are asking for, then you don't need to use a buffer.